How to cache an apiFetch method for a Gutenberg block?
I store WooCommerce product IDs in a custom block:
<!-- wp:custom/block {"woo_products":[123,456]} /-->

I need to call the /wc/v3/products endpoint to retrieve the data from this products but I only like to fetch it if the woo_products actually change.
What I do atm is to wrap it in a useEffect in the edit method:
useEffect(() => {
    if (!woo_products) {
        setEntries([]);
        return;
    }

    const endpoint = '/wc/v3/products';
    apiFetch({
        path: endpoint + '?include=' + woo_products.join(','),
    }).then(
        (result) => {
            setLoading(false);
            setEntries(result);
        },
        (error) => {}
    );
    setLoading(true);
}, [woo_products]);

This causes a refetch every time to block get's selected. I either like to store the info somewhere on the block level or even better globally.
